# Imageview disappearing from layout

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout that I use for several list displays in my application.  For separation purposes, I have an image that I populate with a GradientDrawable between my top banner and the actual listview itself.  When the activity first starts up, the image displays fine, but as soon as I interact with the ListView, the drawable goes away.  If I try to call `bringToFront` on the Imageview it doesn't draw at all in the first place.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here, please help

Here is my xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/listLayout2" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/school_Logo"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/school_Logo" 
        android:textSize="15.0sp"
        android:text="List Title" 
        android:id="@+id/List_Title" 
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/school_Logo" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/school_Logo" 
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/Image_Divider" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/school_Logo" 
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/school_Logo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10.0dip" />

    <Button android:text="Post message" 
        android:id="@+id/postButton" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip" />

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/Image_Divider" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is how I create the drawable for it

```
int[] colors = {Liveblogging_Main.borderColor,Liveblogging_Main.borderColor,Liveblogging_Main.borderColor};
Drawable dividerDrawable = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colors);

ImageView topDivider = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Image_Divider);
topDivider.setImageDrawable(dividerDrawable);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I no longer have access to the project that was having this problem.  I know I resolved the issue somehow, probably by working around it somehow.

Comment: Your code is working fine and able to see GradientDrawable line while scrolling list view also. Try with different colors
int[] colors = {Color.BLUE,Color.GREEN,Color.RED};

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this happens, but I would chose another structure for your layout, one without RelativeLayout. Try something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="Horizontal">
      <ImageView  android:src="@drawable/icon" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/school_Logo"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
                >
       </ImageView>

       <TextView   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/school_Logo" 
                android:textSize="15.0sp"
                android:text="List Title" 
                android:id="@+id/List_Title" 
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/school_Logo" 
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/school_Logo" 
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
                >
       </TextView>
       <Button android:text="Post message" 
                android:id="@+id/postButton" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip">
       </Button>


   </LinearLayout>
   <ImageView  android:id="@+id/Image_Divider" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_below="@+id/school_Logo" 
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/school_Logo"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10.0dip"
                >
   </ImageView>
   <ListView   android:id="@android:id/list" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:scrollingCache="false"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" 
                android:layout_below="@+id/Image_Divider"
                >
   </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This method has the same problem.  Shows up in the beginning, and goes away as soon as i interact with the listview.

Comment: Also this solution ruins the alignment of that button when I want to make it appear, unless you know how I can force it to be aligned to the right side of the screen

Comment: You can make the button align right by setting the gravity attribute:

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the height of the Image_Divider , ImageView to something fixed in dp? I don't see where the height for the ImageView should come from (might be wrong).

And BTW, why aren't you defining the GradientDrawable in XML?
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the bounds of the drawable

```
dividerDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, dividerDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),dividerDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
```

Answer (score 0):

I count even find out single problem in your code ,Dan F :)

your code seem correct , i believe there is some other problem which  not relevant to this provide code ,

however , here is the best example of list view given by google guys
,i wonder if that can help you a bit

[Dev.android.list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)